# Should I prefer to call template metafunctions through a nested typedef or inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion, metaprogramming

I could write a recursive `Contains` metafunction either calling itself by inheritance or by a nested typedef. What is the difference (if any) with regard to the following criteria?

A: compile time and memory needed during compile time.

B: maximum recursion limit (will one allow me to work with a larger number of arguments than the other?)

C: lazy instantiation (will one allow me to elide more instantiations? This may not make a difference in the current example. Would it however if a class had nested typedef of `std::conditional` vs being derived from it?)

1:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Contains : std::false_type {};       //only possible if Ts is empty so does not contain
template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct Contains<T, U, Ts...> : Contains<T, Ts...>{};
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Contains<T, T, Ts...> : std::true_type{};
```

2:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Contains {
    typedef std::false_type Type;
};      //only possible if Ts is empty so does not contain
template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct Contains<T, U, Ts...> {
    typedef typename Contains<T, Ts...>::Type Type;
};
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Contains<T, T, Ts...>{
    typedef std::true_type Type;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use inheritance, the reason being that it naturally allows for tag dispatch:

```
template <typename T>
void f_impl(T const & t, std::true_type derivedB) { ... }
...
template <typename T>
void f(T const & t) {
   f_impl(t, is_base_of<B,T>());
}
```

At the same time inheritance can be used to insert the *nested* information, in this case, a `::value` static member that evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't though of that. Do you know if there is a difference with regard to the maximum recursion depth on MSVC and and GCC? i.e. what if I call Contains with 500 or 1000 arguments, will they fail at a different maximum number?

Comment: @PorkyBrain: Those limits are not defined in the standard, and I don't  know them. But they should be available in the documentation from the vendor. In particular for gcc (I am more familiar with gcc than VS) you can control it with `-ftemplate-depth` although I have never used it.